# Setting filter weights of a convolutional layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im working on a semantic segmentation project which involves dynamic filters in order to learn multiscale representations.

To create these filters I use a Unet backbone and extract the feature maps from the bottleneck layer.
The feature maps are of size H x W X 512, where H is the height of the feature map, W the width and 512 is the number of channels (maps).

These features are passed to a 1x1 convolution to reduce the amount of filters to H X W X 128 and the features are also passed to an adaptive pooling layer to reduce H X W X 512 to k x k x 512, where k is the size of the filter (i.ex. 5).
The filter is then also fed through a 1 x 1 convolution to reduce it to 128.

This gives me a feature map f = H x W x 128 and a filter kernel g of size k x k x 128.

Now I want to convolve f with g and tried the following in keras:

```
conv = Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 5, kernel_initializer = g, trainable = False)(f)
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I just get an error saying:

"Could not interpret initializer identifier: Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape = (5,5,128), dtype = float32)"

Now Iam wondering what Iam doing wrong?

In addition I have to mention that the shape of the output tnesor after average pooling /1x1 conv is (? , 5, 5, 128), where ? is the batch size.
The get the kernel I tried something like:

```
g = g[0,:,:,:]
```

Thanks for any advice,

cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel_initializer argument of the constructor of `Conv2D` does not expect a kernel, but a function that would initialize a kernel. You can read more in the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/#creating-custom-initializers)

If you just want to perform a convolution without trainable weights, you are better off using the tensorflow native function [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) :

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(f,g,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='VALID')
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :-)